# Debugger Message in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea

I am doing a course in Python programming using IntelliJ IDE and currently on how to use the debugger. So I have been given the following line of code with a breakpoint in the 4th line of code:

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
age = int(input("How old are you {0}? ".format(name)))

if age < 18:
    print("Please come back in {} years.".format(18 - age))
elif age == 900:
    print("Sorry, Yoda, you die in the Return of the Jedi.")
else:
    print("You are eligible to vote.")
    print("Please put an X in the box.")
```

After I clicked F8, I got the following message:

"Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)"

But my instructor who did the same got this message:

"Process finished with exit code -1"

Why did this happen and what does my message mean?

Comment: "Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)" is coming from Windows itself, meaning that something other than PyCharm may have terminated the process.

Answer (score 0):

To set a breakpoint on a line of code, click in the gutter area or use the shortcut Ctrl+F8 ( Win/Linux) or ⌘ F8 (macOS).

maybe the shortcut needs a command or control button as well.
it can get tricky sometimes across windows and mac. also if you're using a different layout external keyboard